# Mixing JSON and GeoJSON in a Django answer

Tags: geojson, json, django, serialize

I want to retrieve two separate GeoJSON created from a PostGIS database with Django as well as some valuable information. Here is an example of what I would like to send back to the front end :

```
results = {
    zoom: zoomvariable,
    basemap: basemapvariable,
    center: [xvariable, yvariable],
    user: serialize('geojson', userdata),
    other: serialize('geojson', otherdata)
}
```

But when I use Django's `serialize()` I get a string. And when I return the answer to the front end, I serialize again the JSON to include both GeoJSON using:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(results), 'application/json')
```

This messes up the GeoJSON and adds unwanted backslashes as they are serialized twice.

I'd like to know how I can resolve this issue without having to deserialize both GeoJSONs and reserialize them inside an other JSON? I don't know if mixing JSON and GeoJSON is a good thing to do, but this seems like the best way for me to minimize transactions between the client and the server.